# How could a false memory machine work?

Tags: science-fiction, brain, people

False memories are often used on science fiction, so my question is how could this work?
best answer:

- It’s ok for it to be solely theorized, but the most developed method will be prefered
- machine must be reliable and the effect permanent

there aren't any more requirements.

Comment: Are you asking about injecting memories or rewriting existing ones?

Comment: The technology doesn't yet exist. You could look at what Neuralink wishes to achieve and how they might do it. Answers could range from like, nanomachines to hypnosis, but it's mostly hypothetical. To me, the Q looks to have the same answerability as "how could FTL engines work?"

Comment: Injecting memories

Comment: nanomachines son - alter synapses states and signals rerouting and isolating and creating new connections and states - nanomachines. but if it will be used just for memories wipe rewriting then it is boring. it capable of more. Thus it maybe better to make your own handwavium which u understand better and can make it internally consistent and expand it, reflect it in other actions situations and possibilities.

Comment: It will be used to add 1 memory to all people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Dream Machine**

Most of the time, when we wake up from a dream, we forget about it in a split second. But sometimes the dream seems real enough that we have to convince ourselves that it was just a dream. And in some extremely rare cases (at least it happened to me) when we recall a dream after some time, we have to really think hard to recall if it was actually a dream or reality (given that it was not a fictional one).

If we can find a way to create a dream machine that can forcefully put a real enough dream during the victim's sleep, and then in real life, you show them minor evidence to prove that it was real, It will act as a false memory.

The victim might be confused at first but in the long run, it should work, but the minor (but false) evidence will play an important role in it.

**How does the machine work?**
Some kind of EM waves alter the synapses states or stimulate electrical signals that creates the dream.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of False Memory you want to add to people.

If is something they experienced themselves, then it is a bit harder. For that one, you'll need something akin to Total Recall devices - something that can edit the brain's synapses and create whatever memory you need.

If you want to add a memory about an event that they didn't experience themselves, them that's far easier - and we already have such a machine!

**Plain Old Regular Media**

Information travels really quickly, and most people don't really stop and check if it is true or not. If you want information about a fake event to be disseminated around your population, all you need is a good marketing campaign and enough time. Eventually it will get stuck in the mind of the population, and everyone will remember it - even if it was entirely fake to begin with.